# Is it possible to have line breaks with different styles for each line in jspdf autotable?

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I want to create rows in jspdf autotable where there are two sets of information on separate lines in each cell.

I am currently doing this using the "\n" operator and it works, however I would like the second line in the cell to be a different style (e.g.: smaller font) than the first line or I would like to have a separator (see this image for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7pOa.png).

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I am currently using the plugin in Angular2+

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Added the code below based on suggestion, this only creates two separate lines within a row. I do not know how to style them separately, so don't have any code for that:

```
{'test':'1234'+'\n'+'0.09%'}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the code you've tried?

Comment: Sure, done. Though don't have any code related to actual styling.

Comment: Does anyone have any insights into if this is possible? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by drawing the text yourself using the hooks. In this case the `drawCell` hook is probably most useful.